# Input radio not sending data

Tags: php, contact-form

I have a simple contact form, the html is this part:

```
<!-- CONTACT FORM -->

<form id="contact-form" name="contactform" class="row">
    <!-- CONTACT FORM IMPUT -->
    <div id="input_name" class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Il tuo nome"> 
    </div>
    <div id="input_email" class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"> 
    </div>
    <div id="input_subject" class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero di telefono"> 
    </div>
    <div id="input_message" class="col-md-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Il tuo messaggio..."></textarea>
    </div>   
    <div class="col-md-12 sinistra"><br>Quale servizio ti interessa?<br><br></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 sinistra">
        <input type="radio" name="tipologia" value="standard"> Standard<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 sinistra">
        <input type="radio" name="tipologia" value="avanzato"> Avanzato<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 sinistra">
        <input type="radio" name="tipologia" value="deluxe"> Deluxe<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12"><br></div>
    <!-- CONTACT FORM SUBMIT BUTTON -->
    <div id="form_btn" class="col-md-12">                           
        <input type="submit" value="Invia" id="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-blue">                                  
    </div>
    <!-- CONTACT FORM MESSAGE -->
    <div class="col-md-12 contact-form-msg">
        <span class="loading"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

with this php file

```
 <?
     $name  = $_REQUEST["name"];
     $email = $_REQUEST["email"];
     $subject   = $_REQUEST["subject"];
     $msg   = $_POST["msg"];
     $tipologia = $_POST['tipologia'] ;
     $to    = "info@gmail.com"; 
     if (isset($email) && isset($name) && isset($msg) ) {
         $email_subject = "$name ha inviato una richiesta di ordine"; 
         $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
         $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
         $headers .= "Da: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n" ;
         $msg     = "Da: $name<br/> Email: $email <br/> Telefono: $subject <br/>    
                     Tipologia: $tipologia <br/> Messaggio: $msg";

         $mail =  mail($to, $email_subject, $msg, $headers);
         if($mail)
         {
             echo 'success';
         }
         else
         {
             echo 'failed';
         }
     }
 ?>
```

but I have a problem with radio input, the form works but doesn't pass the value of radio to email, so the email has the Tipologia without the radio selected for the form... What could be the error?

Comment: If you are not selecting any radio button..u won't recive any post value related to "tipologia" form element

Answer (score 1):

`<form>` defaults to a GET method if POST isn't implied.

You're using two POST arrays.

So... use a POST method and all POST arrays.

Either way, everything must match.

You should also check if the radio buttons are set or not, or any other you wish to include.